# Render HTML on Node.js Express (Include HTML code in another HTML file)

Tags: node.js, html, express

I'm using a Node.js Server with Express-Framework installed and have a problem combining two different html-files.

I have a basic template.html file with a `<div id="content">` in it. Now I want to include content.html within this div before sending the data to the client.

How can this be done?

Comment: What is HTML code? Anyway, you could look at [jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) and the [block append/depend](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a12).

Comment: Well it's just a simple HTML file with a few div's in it and I want to include HTML code from another file into one of the div's from the main html file...

Comment: Like I said, try to look at the express example with jade, they extend a skeleton template and replace blocks in it. So at the homepage you extend the skeleton and replace `block content` with the homepage content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use EJS because it's the most straight-forward templating language, but the same idea applies for jade or whatever you might use. To enable this in express after running `npm install ejs`:

```
app.engine('.ejs', require('ejs').__express);
```

When you send your response, run:

```
res.render('content.html.ejs');
```

Spit your template.html into `views/header.html.ejs` and `views/footer.html.ejs`, and include them in `views/content.html.ejs` like this:

```
<% include header.ejs %>
  Content Here
<% include footer.ejs %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found angular-express-seed and I'm using jade now